# How to make a .htaccess to redirect all request from the url to get.php?u= but exclusing exsisting files

Tags: javascript, php, html, .htaccess

I'm new to `.htaccess` and I'm stuck with a problem I can't fix.

I have my website URL (for this example `https://example.com`) and I want each time I visit `https://example.com/example` to redirect to `get.php?u=example` but exclude the redirect if it is a real file for example: `https://example.com/index.html`.

I've tried using redirects and exceptions, none of them worked.

Comment: please show what you have tried so far!

Comment: You've tagged your question `javascript`, `php` and `html` - what does your question have to do with these technologies?

Answer (score 0):

1)
on top of get.php add array of html files names, do a in_array check, if true read and echo html file contents

```
$files = ['index.html', 'example.html'];

if(in_array($_GET['u'], $files))
 {
  echo file_get_contents($_GET['u']);
  exit;
 }
```

OR 
2)
prefix your files with a common identifier and add a condition in .htaccess to not redirect matching prefix URLs

Answer (score 0):

You can use mod_rewrite at the top of your `.htaccess` file. For example:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule (.*) /get.php?u=$1 [R,L]
```

This issues a temporary (302) redirect of a URL of the form `/example` to `/get.php?u=example`, except where `/example` maps to a physical file on the filesystem. (Directories will still be redirected.)

However, if you want to *rewrite* the URL instead (ie. don't change the URL in the browser's address bar), then change the `RewriteRule` directive to read:

```
RewriteRule (.*) get.php?u=$1 [L]
```

ie. Remove the `R` (`redirect`) flag and the slash prefix (which is not necessary).